Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory. Please make sure that the kernel module `vmmon' is loaded. VMWare Workstation PRO
I am running Zorin 17
uname -a
Linux N100 6.5.0-41-generic #41~22.04.2-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jun  3 11:32:55 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
I was using workstation player and recently upgraded to Workstation Pro 17.5.
I have my VM set to start when the machine boots, which was working fine, now i am getting the following error:
Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory. Please make sure that the kernel module `vmmon' is loaded.
I have seen this has been a common error as detailed by these threads;
VMWare 15 Error on Ubuntu 18.4 - Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory
VMWare workstation 15 Pro pn Ubuntu 18.4.03 LTS - Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory
Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory
https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/315309/cannot-open-devvmmon-no-such-file-or-dir.html
However i have been through every solution on these threads and nothing works.

Manually created and signed the keys
Used Rune1979s automated script
Tested the key to confirm it is enrolled;
"mokutil --test-key vmware_key.der
Failed to accesss kernel trusted keyring: Required key not available
vmware_key.der is already enrolled"
uninstalled/ reinstalled the application fully
turned off Secure Boot in the bios, seems like it was never on in the first place.

I still have this issue when i log in.
Is there anything else i can do here?
Thanks!

That OS is off topic on this Ubuntu only support site. sorry.

Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Zorin forum.  (One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Zorin so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux found in the on-topic link)
